# What is consuming my disk?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, io

I have a Win8 64bit Dell XPS One computer that continuously has trouble operating because the disk I/O is at >99%! I need a way to find out what is causing this. The Task Manager is no help because the System is consuming it and I don't know what part of the system is hogging it all. Please help me diagnose and fix this.

Thank you![image]

Comment: follow my steps here: http://pastebin.com/AyxAVU60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try SysInternal's Process Explorer. It gives a more detailed picture of what is running under certain processes.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx
[image]

Comment: Yes I am aware of this tool but in this case found it not helpful because I was experiencing hardware failure which could not be identified to software process.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another good tool is [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). It allows you to see the activity of processes running. You basically start it and it begins collecting information.

You can then sort by clicking on the headers and find what is driving all the I/O activity.

Answer (score -1):

There is a good software tool that i use called windirstat it displays an image of your hard disk with different colors for each type of files, the files are represented as squares, more the file is huge more the square is big in the image, it's free 
http://windirstat.info/

Comment: he wants to know which process hogs the disk and not which folder uses most space.